# Shortest distance between two points

Tags: geometry, geodesic

Everyone knows that the shortest distance between two points is a straight line. How can we prove it mathematically?

Comment: What space are you referring to?

Comment: @Luuuuuke probably he mean Euclidean geometry.

Comment: This question is a duplicate of "https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/833434/why-is-a-straight-line-the-shortest-distance-between-two-points" , "https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/720171/trying-to-prove-shortest-distance-between-two-points" and so all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The shortest distance between any two distinct points is the line segment joining them.How can I see why this is true?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/181110/the-shortest-distance-between-any-two-distinct-points-is-the-line-segment-joinin)

Answer (score 1):

If $y$ is a $C^2$ function of $x$ and traces a curve between points $(a,c)$ and $(b,d)$, then the length of the curve is 
$$
    \ell = \int_a^b \sqrt{1+(y')^2}\,dx
$$
This is the kind of functional that we can apply the [calculus of variations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculus_of_variations) to.  According the Euler-Lagrange equations (see link), the quantity $\ell$ is minimized when
$$
    \frac{d}{dx} \frac{\partial}{\partial y'}\sqrt{1+(y')^2} = \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\sqrt{1+(y')^2}
$$
Therefore,
$$
    \frac{d}{dx}\frac{y'}{\sqrt{1+(y')^2}} = 0
    \implies \frac{y''}{(1+(y')^2)^{3/2}} = 0
    \implies y'' = 0
$$
If $y'' = 0$, the curve is a straight line.

Answer (score 0):

This follows from the [Euler-Lagrange equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation) from the calculus of variations. Let $(a,y(a)),(b,y(b))$ be two points in the plane, where $y$ is a differentiable function on $[a,b]$. The lenght $S$ of this curve  between $a \le x \le b$ is given by:
$$S =\int_{a}^{b}\sqrt{1+\bigg{(}\frac{dy}{dx}\bigg{)}^{2}}dx$$
So we would like to find out which curve $y$ minimizes $S$. Write $F(y') = \sqrt{1+(y')^{2}}$. We have:
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial y} F = 0 \quad \mbox{and} \quad \frac{\partial}{\partial y'}F = \frac{y'}{\sqrt{1+y'}}$$
Thus, using Euler-Lagrange we have:
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial y}F - \frac{d}{dx}\bigg{(}\frac{\partial}{\partial y'}F\bigg{)} = 0 \Rightarrow -\frac{d}{dx}\bigg{[}\frac{y'}{\sqrt{1+(y')^{2}}}\bigg{]} = 0 \hspace{1cm} (1)$$
The solution of equation (1) is given by:
$$ y = \alpha x + \beta$$
which is exactly the equation of a straight line.